# Exchange 365 Spam Filter Policy Block Domain TLD

Tags: spam, microsoft-office-365

We migrated to cloud from on premise Exchange 2010. In Sonicwall ESA, I was able to block TLDs (Top Level Domains). In the Exchange Admin Center, I see I can set individual or additional "Rules", however, no option I can see to test TLD against a dictionary to block the domain. In the Microsoft 365 Security Center, under Policies > Anti-Spam > (new policy), it appears I can edit "Allowed and blocked senders and domains" but do not see how to block against a list of TLDs, or if should enter ".domain" or just "domain". Locating the documentation of settings seems difficult to locate.

In the "Tenant Allow/Block Lists" it appears to allow entry of only 20 domains and might be temporary.

Where would be best to Create a dictionary of TLDs, and Create an organizational block of these sending domains?

In example, we would get spam from .bar, .date, .webcam, etc. I realize its a losing battle, but my list of about 75 TLDs was effective in a large reduction of daily spam. Now that we are on 365, they have returned to an offensive level with the default 365 filters.

If a spam filter connector is the best way to proceed, can you provide some experience with SonicWall, or TrendMicro, or your vendor of choice vs the cost, setup, and management of the hosted filter service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the Transport Rules of O365.

Exchange Admin Centre -> Mail Flow -> Rules

Apply this rule if…. The send address matches;

In the condition box you need to entrer the domain that way, **`\.domain$`**, or **`\.webcam$`**, etc..

And select to Reject the email.

Comment: Seems in 2016 an exact issue was had. And the result of MS support is to do an EXCEPT and a domain list, which is not viable (would have to enter all accepted domains instead). We have .com.tw and .co.tw , in example, but from many countries. What I am looking for is option to EXCLUDE a list. [link]https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/blocking-tld-top-level-domain-in-office365-small/353e9e4f-713f-493e-9388-d5eb37ac6fc9[/link]

Comment: @AdamRoof the answer is correct. Create a transport rule and block the domains (using regex syntax) based on sender address. Send them to quarantine or reject them all together if you want. It’s fully configurable.

Comment: @Appleoddity no where in "spam filter of 0365" do I see where to apply any rules with regex against the send address. Where are the transport rules you speak of?

Comment: @AdamRoof you’re right. It is not spam filter rules - I overlooked that. It’s a transport rule, like I said. https://techwizard.cloud/2016/01/08/block-sender-in-office-365-based-on-regex-pattern/amp/

Comment: I will edit, I typed too fast too (and the regex lost their formating due to the editor, correcting that too)

Comment: Ok, thanks for the edits! Helps clarify. I've added a rule and action of generate incident report, and test without policy tips, along with a few common TLDs we receive. I will let you know if get some matches, shouldnt be long :(

Comment: It WORKS! EAC > Mail Flow > Rules > + Create New Rule > Name: Block Bad Domains > Apply this rule if: The sender is located "Outside the Organization" (prob not needed) > Click More options... (blue link toward bottom) > Add condition button > And The sender address matches... > enter your domain list one at a time to list " \.bad$ " format works. > Do the following... > delete the message without notifying anyone (or generate incident report)  > Enforce (or Test with Policy Tips) > Stop Processing more rules (set priority to 0